# ¿Cómo lograr que se ejecute un script cuando el usuario confirme una acción?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, sweetalert2

Estoy haciendo un eliminar de registros con la librería SweetAlert y quiero que cuando el usuario le de click al boton eliminar le aparezca un mensaje de advertencia. Cuando presiono el botón eliminar me aparece el mensaje y luego se ejecuta el eliminar, quiero evitar eso, solo quiero que se ejecute cuando el usuario confirme..

Esta acción la realizo con Jquery y Ajax:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
            text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
        }).then(function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Eliminado!',
                    'Se eliminó una charla.',
                    'success'
                ).then(function () {

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
                                data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim() },
                                success: function (rpta) {

                                },
                                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                                }
                           });

                    });
            } else {

            }
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `windows.confirm()`, es un metodo que despliega un dialogo que muestra los botones 'si' y 'no', te quedaría así:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
            text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
        }).then(function () {
            // Aqui implementamos su uso
            if (window.confirm('Seguro que deseas borrar la charla?')) {
                Swal.fire(
                    'Eliminado!',
                    'Se eliminó una charla.',
                    'success'
                ).then(function () {

                        $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
                                data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim() },
                                success: function (rpta) {

                                },
                                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                                }
                           });

                    });
            } else {

            }
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Acabo de implementarlo y no llego a funcionar. El windows que pusiste en el if en realidad la sintaxis es window, pero aún asi con ese cambio no llegue al resultado

Answer (score 1):

Hola creo que podrias probar con algo como esto.

```
        <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".btn-eliminar").on("click", function () {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Está seguro que desea eliminar esta Charla?',
            text: "No podrá recuperar los datos!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCloseButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Sí, eliminarlo!',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            closeOnConfirm: true,
            html: true

        },
         function () { //confirmar
                $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: '@Url.Action("EliminarCharla", "Charlas")',
                 data: { id: $(this).parent().siblings(".td-id").text().trim() },
                 success: function (rpta) {

                                },
                                error: function (req, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert('Ooops, something happened: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
                                }
                           });
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: No tuve éxito amigo @EdgarVazquez

Comment: Te marco algún tipo de error?

Answer (score 0):

yo he implementado de esta forma`SweetAlert`

```
 swal({
      title: '¿Desea eliminar?',
      text: '',
      type: 'question',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonText: 'Si',
      cancelButtonText: 'No',
      confirmButtonColor: 'rgb(13,165,80)',
      cancelButtonColor: 'rgb(160,0,87)',
      allowOutsideClick: false,
      allowEscapeKey: false
    }).then((results) => {
      if (results.value) {
        // aquí puedes mostrar un mensaje de eliminación correcta
      } else {
        // aquí se valida si el usuario no quiso eliminar
      }
    });
```

Comment: No es necesario el `else` , solo quitalo si no lo necesitas

Comment: No tuve éxito amigo @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO, estaba seguro que funcionaría, ya que el código que me mostraste es de la documentación de SweetAlert pero aun asi no tuve éxito.

Comment: Muéstrame como estas haciendo muéstrame el html y el script completo, yo hago una prueba